# Nested cursor, While Loop SQL

Tags: sql, while-loop, cursor, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into two tables(at one shot 100 to 150 rows on both tables). First Table Primary key have a reference with Second Table Foreign key.I Read that Cursor is having problem for @@Fetch_Status is global variable. Which is best way to loop and do data insertion in both tables Cursor or While Loop or any other.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
FirstTablePK [int] NOT NULL, --Mannual Increment(Not Identity)
Description [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FirstTablePK)
)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
SecondTablePK [int] NOT NULL, --Mannual Increment(Not Identity)
FirstTablePK [int] NOT NULL, -- Foreign Key Reference with Table1
Description [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SecondTablePK),
CONSTRAINT FK_Table1 FOREIGN KEY (FirstTablePK) REFERENCES Table1(FirstTablePK)
)
```

Thanks in Advance.
Hari

Comment: It's near-impossible to answer a question phrased like this. Please show your table structure, some sample data, the result you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Comment: According to performance while loop is best rather than cursor...

Comment: Hi Mureinik I have added Table structure.

Comment: what are the source tables, from which data to be inserted into these 2 tables ?

Answer (score 0):

A cursor is not often used to look up foreign keys.  It's faster and easier to use a set-based query:

```
insert  into SaleOrder
        (remarks, product_id, customer_id, ...)
select  'please deliver fast'
,       (select id from Products where name = 'Car Oil')
,       (select id from Customers where name = 'India Corp')
,       ...
```